# FluentValidation: Exclude the "Severity:..." suffix from the messages

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I upgraded to the latest version of FluentValidation at this time (11.9.0) from an older version, and I noticed that now the error messages in my app contain the suffix: "Severity: Error". Leaving aside the idea, that, imo, when changes are made to a library, extra care should be taken to leave the existing behaviour unperturbed as much as possible, is it possible to turn off the addition of this suffix?

See [ValidationException](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/a796e460fff7339bc686e146d70cc94811f15be5/src/FluentValidation/ValidationException.cs#L31).

```
public ValidationException(string message, IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors, bool appendDefaultMessage)
    : base(appendDefaultMessage ? $"{message} {BuildErrorMessage(errors)}" : message) {
    Errors = errors;
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a new ValidationException
/// </summary>
/// <param name="errors"></param>
public ValidationException(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors) : base(BuildErrorMessage(errors)) {
    Errors = errors;
}

private static string BuildErrorMessage(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors) {
    var arr = errors.Select(x => $"{Environment.NewLine} -- {x.PropertyName}: {x.ErrorMessage} Severity: {x.Severity.ToString()}");
    return "Validation failed: " + string.Join(string.Empty, arr);
}
```

The `BuildErrorMessage` method is called from a number of constructors. I am not sure how I can avoid its call.

And one other thing. I attached some custom validation methods to the object itself that is validated. The default message displays the PropertyName followed by colon. If the x.PropertyName is null the message will contain: `-- :` which looks weird. On top of that, sometimes the names used in the code don't reflect concepts that make sense to the end users.

Thanks

Update: After reading the code, one way would be to extend AbstractValidator and override [RaiseValidationException](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/a796e460fff7339bc686e146d70cc94811f15be5/src/FluentValidation/AbstractValidator.cs#L530) to call the ValidationException constructor that doesn't decorate the message:

```
    protected override void RaiseValidationException(ValidationContext<T> context, ValidationResult result)
        => throw new ValidationException(result.Errors, false);
```

Unfortunately there is no constructor that takes the boolean flag, so I would need to extend the exception as well.

Comment: Can you modify BuildErrorMessage? If so use this instead: private static string BuildErrorMessage(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors) {
    var arr = errors.Select(x => $"{Environment.NewLine} -- {x.PropertyName}: {x.ErrorMessage} ");
    return "Validation failed: " + string.Join(string.Empty, arr);
}

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this would imply that I have to build the library myself. I wanted to be able to modify the message without touching the library.

Answer (score 0):

My solution as linqpad 7 script with FluentValidator 11.9.0 added as dependency :

```cs
void Main()
{
    var dto = new SomeDto();
    var validators = new List<(string label, AbstractValidator<SomeDto> validator)> {
        ("Old message", new SomeValidator()), ("New message", new SomeValidatorEx())
    };

    validators.ForEach(it =>
    {
        try
        {
            it.validator.ValidateAndThrow(dto);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{it.label}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    });
    
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class ValidationExceptionEx : ValidationException
{
    private static string BuildErrorMessage(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors)
    {
        var arr = errors.Select(
          x =>
          {
              // var propertyName = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.PropertyName) ? "" : x.PropertyName + ": ";

              return $"{Environment.NewLine} -- {x.ErrorMessage}";
          });

        return "Validation failed: " + string.Join(string.Empty, arr);
    }


    public ValidationExceptionEx(List<ValidationFailure> errors) : base(BuildErrorMessage(errors), errors, false)
    {
    }
}

public class AbstractValidatorEx<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    protected override void RaiseValidationException(ValidationContext<T> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        throw new ValidationExceptionEx(result.Errors);
    }
}

class SomeDto { public int? SomeProperty { get; set; } }

class SomeValidatorEx : AbstractValidatorEx<SomeDto>
{
    public SomeValidatorEx()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
          .NotNull()
          .WithMessage(d => "Some Message");

        RuleFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
          .NotNull();
    }
}

class SomeValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeDto>
{
    public SomeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
          .NotNull()
          .WithMessage(d => "Some Message");

        RuleFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
          .NotNull();
    }
}
```

It produces the output:

```
Old message: Validation failed:
 -- SomeProperty: Some Message Severity: Error
 -- SomeProperty: 'Some Property' must not be empty. Severity: Error
New message: Validation failed:
 -- Some Message
 -- 'Some Property' must not be empty.
```

Now all my validators will have to inherit `AbstractValidatorEx` (bulk search & replace).